# How to calculate the payback period when income is reinvested?

Tags: financial-literacy, compound-interest

Could someone please show me how to calculate the payback period with compounded interest? So if I had a initial investment of $100, paying 1.5% interest annually that is reinvested, how do I calculate how long it would take to recover my initial investment?

Many thanks

Comment: what is the investment in? A CD?, a bond?, a savings account? a share of a company or mutual fund?

Comment: What do you mean "recover" your initial investment? You haven't _lost_ anything to recover. Do you mean how long it will take to _double_?

Comment: Also if it's reinvested you're not recovering anything.... the interest is just as lost as the initial investment. After a year you'd have 101.50 invested with nothing "recovered"

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your investment had a 10% fee and you want to know when it reaches $100

```
with s = initial investment
     a = target amount
     r = annual effective rate
     n = number of years

s = 90
a = 100
r = 0.015

n =  log(a/s)/log(1 + r) = 7.07658
```

So it would reach 100 in just over 7 years, i.e.

After 7 years

```
a = s (1 + r)^7 = 99.89
```

After 8 years

```
a = s (1 + r)^8 = 101.38
```

Answer (score 0):

An investment earning 1.5% interest will double in 48 years according to: 72 / 1.5 . That's an approximate method.

An investment earning 1.5% interest will double in 46.56 years according to: ln(2) / ln(1.015) . That's yearly compounding. The value 1.015 relates to 1 + (1.5 / 1 year / 100).

An investment earning 1.5% interest will double in 554.86 months according to: ln(2) / ln(1.00125) . That's monthly compounding. The value 1.00125 relates to 1 + (1.5 / 12 months / 100).

An investment earning 1.5% interest and compounded monthly will slightly more than double in 555 months according to a run of this computer program:

Begin

c:= 0;

a:= 100;

While a < 200 Do

Begin

b:= a * 0.015 / 12;

a:= a + b;

c:= c + 1;

End;

WriteLn(a:10:2);

WriteLn(c:10);

ReadLn;

End.

Comment: If you use `b:= a * 0.015 / 12` that is a nominal rate of 1.5% compounded monthly, which is not the same as an effective annual rate of 1.5%. (See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation).) For an equivalent calculation you should use `b:= a * x / 12` where `x = 12 ((1 + 0.015)^(1/12) - 1) = 0.0148979`. That is, `x` is the equivalent nominal annual rate compounded monthly. This figure will give you the same result as the annual one, but in terms of months.

Comment: Using 0.0148979 in the computer program results in 559 months as 46.58 years.

Comment: Yes.  Your program counts whole months and slightly overshoots the 200 target. 
The same result is obtained by `12 * ln(2) / ln(1.015) = 558.67 months` which rounds up to 559 whole months.

Comment: I included ln(2)  /  ln(1.015) to begin with. A conversion from years to months is not worth mentioning.

Comment: Oh, for monthly compounding it's ln(2) / ln(1.00125) and results in 554.86 months. The computer program which compounds monthly results in 555 months when using 1.5% as 0.015 .

Comment: The program and log calculations produce the same results as long as the terminology is consistent as to whether the rate is nominal or effective.

Comment: The ln natural-log formula uses an interest-rate-per-period to realize the result of periodic-compounding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72 .

Comment: However, the interest-rate-per-period for a 1.5% effective annual rate and a 1.5% nominal annual rate compounded monthly is `(1 + 0.015)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.00124149` and `0.015/12 = 0.00125` respectively, as described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation

Comment: The OP's question states "*1.5% interest annually*". In the absence of any mention of compounding frequency the implication is that it is an effective rate (or nominal rate compounded annually, which is the same). The equivalent nominal rate compounded monthly is `12 * ((1 + 0.015)^(1/12) - 1) = 1.48979 %`